# Duplicate classes when using Maven AspectJ weave dependencies

Tags: java, maven, aspectj

We are using the Maven AspectJ plugin to build our web application. It makes use of "weaveDependencies" to add aspects to some dependency jar files.

Now we end up with two versions of some classes in the web application archive, one in `WEB-INF/classes` and one in the original jar file in `WEB-INF/lib`. It seems that only the one in `classes` has the aspects.

I am afraid that this can cause problems.

What is the best way to fix this?

The same problem is discussed (without solution) [over at the Eclipse forums](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/483453/).

---

The whole pom.xml itself is huge, and of course the sub-projects that are included have their own, too. I hope the extract below from the WAR project is informative enough.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
        <filters>
            <filter>${basedir}/src/etc/${environment}/environment.properties</filter>
        </filters>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version> <!-- NB: do use 1.3 or 1.3.x due to MASPECTJ-90 - wait for 1.4 -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- NB: You must use Maven 2.0.9 or above or these are ignored (see 
            MNG-2972) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <outxml>true</outxml>
        <aspectLibraries>
            <aspectLibrary>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            </aspectLibrary>
        </aspectLibraries>
        <weaveDependencies>
            <weaveDependency>
                <groupId>OURPROJECT</groupId>
                <artifactId>OURPROJECT-api</artifactId>
            </weaveDependency>
            <weaveDependency>
                <groupId>OURPROJECT</groupId>
                <artifactId>OURPROJECT-service</artifactId>
            </weaveDependency>
        </weaveDependencies>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Please show your pom file?

Comment: @khmarbaise: Added an extract, hope that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a servlet container and inside a WAR, the classes inside WEB-INF/classes always have precedence over classes with the exact same name found inside a jar in WEB-INF/lib.

This is a quote from the [servlet spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-2.4-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/servlet-2_4-fr-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1393964665_3a481da86f46752586dc7d3332b3f143):

> The Web application class loader must load classes from the WEB-INF/
>   classes directory   ﬁrst, and then from library JARs in the
>   WEB-INF/lib directory.

This has been so since at least Servlet 2.4. This allows an application to selectively patch just a few library classes without having to repackage jars manually or via maven plugins.

In your case you can be certain that the classes with the aspects will always be taken,  as they are in WEB-INF/classes and have priority over classes in WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: So the AspectJ plugin is supposed to work that way, and I am supposed to live with the duplication (and the inability to just patch my war file by swapping our jar files, because those are being overridden by hundreds of individual class files)? Why are the jar files included in the web application at all, then? Shouldn't the plugin filter them out?

Comment: try to declare the dependencies OURPROJECT-api and OURPROJECT-service to maven scope `provided`, meaining they will be available at compile time for the plugin, but not included in the WAR. this would remove the duplication

Comment: I like that suggestion about `provided`. But this depends on *all* files in those jars being duplicated by the weaver, not just Java classes (or even just Java classes with annotations/aspects). I'll check if that seems to be the case.

Comment: The non-class resources from the jar files are also found in WEB-INF/classes now. So `provided` seems like a good solution. Accepting this answer.